# Generalise LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have several queries identical except for the subject and parameters of the query and I am trying to formulate a 'generalised'  query to avoid multiple lines of almost identical code.

I have the following code:

Code Snippet

```
 private IEnumerable doQuery(string rangeVar,
                             DataSet dsSubTable,
                             string qrySubject,
                             string subTableKey,
                             string subTableDescription,
                             string fldName)
    {
        qryStart = dtmpickFrom.Value;
        qryEnd = dtmpickTo.Value;

        var groupQuery =
            from trans in dataSet.Transaction    
            where ((trans.T_Date >= qryStart) && (trans.T_Date <= qryEnd))
            from rangeVar in dataSet.dsSubTable  <<<<<<
                 where trans.qrySubject == rangeVar.subTableKey

            select new    ..... <snipped>
```

The compiler won't accept the dsSubTable (shown <<<<<) with the following message:

> 'ExpenditureLINQDataSets.Expenditure' does not contain a definition for 'dsSubTable'
>   and no extension method 'dsSubTable' accepting a first argument of type 'ExpenditureLINQDataSets.Expenditure'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

I realise this, of course (if I try to give dsSubTable a type of Expenditure..... only the actual table names defined in my DataSet  appear in Intellisense.)

Is it possible to generalise such LINQ queries or must I live with multiple, allmost identical queries in my code?

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to accomplish it, but the code / question is very confusing as I don't have any idea of how your Expenditure class works. Could you try to recreate the scenario in some new test code which does not depend on all your business objects, to help others understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in dsSubTable as a DataTable then you can use it directly in a from blah in dsSubTable.

But it feels like your abusing Linq.  The power of Linq is that it is not Sql, so why are you writing a method that instead of string concatenating Sql together, you're building up a Linq expression.

Linq allows you to think of your data in terms of Sets and that's what I find really powerful about it.  I encourage you to think about what you are trying to accomplish when you call 'doQuery' and encode those queries as first class operations.

Comment: I don't think I'm abusing LINQ. I'm using it extensively in my application. I just wanted to know if I could  avoid scattering t a lot of very similar queries through my code.

Comment: Oh it has nothing to do with how much you're using linq.  I'm just saying that Linq allows you to take a conceptual step up, what you're trying to do doesn't reflect that.  I know I sound like an ass, but there are probably more Model and Architecture concerns implied by your question then anything

Comment: Also, damn character limits on a comment field :-P

Comment: My program is a straightforward WinForms app used by myself on my PC. I don't see any particular Model/Architecture issues, just a desire for neat code and elimination of numerous 'almost identical' queries.

Comment: http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx I don't know if this will help, but you might find it cool :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and see how I might use the techniques described.